# Como identificar o focus em um div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Galera montei um sistema de input com o mesmo layout do android.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente no `input` parcelas, porém o `input` fornecedor fica dentro de uma `div`, pois tenho que adicionar um botão no lugar do x.

O problema e que quando fico com o mouse sobre ele o alinha border fica azul, e quando saio ela volta a ficar preta.

Preciso deixar ela igual ao input parcelas, ou seja quando for clicada tem que ficar azul independente se o mouse esta sobre ela ou não.

Segue o meu código:

```js
$('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');

$('.form_campos_box').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parents('.box').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.control-label {
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-group.focused .control-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form_campos {
  height: 20px;
  color: #484848;
  z-index: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #484848;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.form_campos:hover,
.form_campos:focus {
  border-color: #1E90FF;
}

.form_campos_numeros {
  width: 123px;
}



/* BOX INPUT E BOTAO */

.box {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  height: 44px;
  border-color: #484848;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.box input {
  outline: 0;
  width: 230px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.box_bt {
  margin-top: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box_bt:hover {
  color: #1E90FF;
}

.box:hover {
  border-color: #1E90FF;
}

.box.focused .control-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form_campos_box {
  color: #484848;
  z-index: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}
/* FIM BOX INPUT E BOTAO */
```

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='numParcelas'>PARCELAS*</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_numeros' id='numParcelas' name='numParcelas'>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class='box'>
  <label class='control-label' for='auto'>FORNECEDOR*</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos_box' id='auto' name='nome'>
  <div class="box_bt">
    <i class='demo-icon'>X</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bp3fsk3b/)

Comment: Atribui diretamente no `CSS` o `:focus` ao `input`, sem `jQuery`.
Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ojgdkjtc/

Comment: ai não da certo, preciso manter o layout que montei

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma `div` que possa ser focada se você atribuir um `tabindex` nela.

Por ter um indicador tipo *`index`*, ou seja, por índice, sendo 0 o primeiro item, o atributo `tabindex` de valor "0" é o padrão.
**Dica:** você pode atribuir o valor "-1" para um `tabindex`, porém ele só poderá ser focado via código e nunca pelo usuário.

**HTML**

```
<div>Elemento sem tabindex (não focável)</div>
<div tabindex="0">Elemento normal (focável por script ou pelo clique/usuário)</div>
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted">Elemento não focável pelo usuário (focável pelo script)</div>
<div id="test">Setar foco</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
div:focus {
    background-color: Aqua;
}
</style>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('scripted').focus();
};
</script>
```

```html
<div>1) Elemento sem tabindex (não focável)</div>
<div tabindex="0">2) Elemento normal (focável por script ou pelo clique/usuário)</div>
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted">3) Elemento não focável pelo usuário (focável pelo script)</div>
<button id="foco">Focar elemento 3</button>


<style>
  div:focus {
    background-color: Aqua;
  }
</style>


<script>
  document.getElementById('foco').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('scripted').focus();
  };
</script>
```

Espero que isso te ajude em alguma coisa ou sirva para seu projeto!

**Links úteis:**
["How to focus div?" em Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042431/how-to-focus-div)
["Change focus into particular div" em Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777580/change-focus-into-particular-div)
["Tabindex | HTML" em Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: bom tentei fazer desta forma, porem quanto clico no input dentro da div ela não fica selecionada. seque o código para vc ver https://jsfiddle.net/fcfhxznb/

Comment: @Hugo, você precisa atribuir o método em um botão ou em outro evento. No meu código, atribuí um botão e no evento `onclick` ele chamava o método pelo atributo `id` do botão.

Comment: tem com vc me mandar um exemplo pelo jsfiddle, com o código que postei no meu comentário anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo, a solução aqui é bem simples, você deve passar a ver cada um destes conjunto de `elementos` como um `componente`, por exemplo os `elementos` abaixo:

```
<div class='box'>
  <label class='control-label' for='auto'>FORNECEDOR*</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos_box' id='auto' name='nome'>
  <div class="box_bt">
    <i class='demo-icon'>X</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

ao meu ver, `label[for='auto']`, `input#auto` e o `i.demon-icon` formam um unico componente, e todos são agrupados pela `div.box`

neste caso é interresante que ações em qual quer um dos elementos seja refletida no componente inteiro, para isto iremos adicionar classes à `div.box`.

```
var elem = {};
elem.auto = $("#auto");
elem.box = $(".box");

elem.auto.on("input", function (event) {
  elem.box.toggleClass("md-has-value", elem.auto.val());
});

elem.auto.on("focusin", function (event) {
  elem.box.addClass("md-focus");
});

elem.auto.on("focusout", function (event) {
  elem.box.removeClass("md-focus");
});
```

no script acima, sempre que o `input#auto` estiver com focus, a `div.box` vai possuir a classe `md-focus`, e quando o `input#auto`, a `div.box` vai possuir a classe `md-has-value`.

então agora no lugar de setar a cor com

```
.box_bt:hover {
   color: #1E90FF;
}
```

você vai setar com

```
.box.md-focus i ,
.box.md-focus label {
  color: #1E90FF;
  opacity: 1;
}

.box.md-focus {
  border-color: #1E90FF;
}
```

no exemplo acima estou aplicando a cor quando o input ganha focus, e não quanto o mouse passa sobre o mesmo, pois isto está mais proximo do comportamento do Android...

Em todo caso, você pode substinuit os eventos `focusin` e `focusiout`, pelos `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`...

no exemplo acima, tambem faço um toggle da classe `ms-has-value`, pois você pode querer aplicar um efeito no label caso o input tenha algum valor.

Comment: bom tentei fazer aqui, mas não eu certo. tem como vc conferir se fiz algo errado. Segue link: https://jsfiddle.net/bp3fsk3b/2/

Comment: @Hugo, realizei uns ajustes, eu acabei confundindo o nome dos eventos... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp3fsk3b/3/)

Comment: ok e isso mesmo, porém a animação não esta funcionando mais, ela tem quer ser igual a 1º input, quando vc clica o texto sobe, e o texto não pode mudar a cor do texto, apenas da borda. Tem como resolver isso?

Comment: @HugoSabrina, como já havia sugerido antes, inclui os eventos `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`, então passei a fazer o toggle de mais uma classe na `div.box`, no caso `md-mouse`... tanto o `md-focus` e `md-mouse` estão tornando a bordar azul... porem apenas o `md-focus` torna o `label` mais opaco. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp3fsk3b/4/)

Comment: bom então não tem como fazer a animação com a borda azul?

Answer (score 0):

É esse o resultado que você quer?

> Desculpem por reativar, me confundi com as datas e achei que fosse desse ano. Agora que vi Fev de 2016. :|

O que me mudei foi adicionar mais uma classe no `toggle` do `jquery` para cada `div`, e criar essas classes no `css`. Parece que deu certo.

```js
$('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function (e) {

    $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused focus', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));

}).trigger('blur');

$('.form_campos_box').on('focus blur', function (e) {

    $(this).parents('.box').toggleClass('focused focus', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0))
 
}).trigger('blur');
```

```css
body {
font-family: 'Verdana';
font-size: 12px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-color: #484848;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;

}

.control-label {
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-group.focused .control-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form_campos {
  height: 20px;
  color: #484848;
  z-index: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}



.form_campos_numeros {
  width: 123px;
}



/* BOX INPUT E BOTAO */

.box {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  height: 44px;
  border-color: #484848;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
}


.box input {
  outline: 0;
  width: 230px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.box_bt {
  margin-top: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box_bt:hover {
  color: #1E90FF;
}


.box.focused .control-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form_campos_box {
  color: #484848;
  z-index: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

.box.focus, .form-group.focus {
     border-color: #1E90FF;}

.box:hover, .form-group:hover {
     border-color: #1E90FF;}

/* FIM BOX INPUT E BOTAO *
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='form-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='numParcelas'>PARCELAS*</label>
    <input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_numeros' id='numParcelas' name='numParcelas'>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class='box'>
    <label class='control-label' for='auto'>FORNECEDOR*</label>
    <input type='text' class='form_campos_box' id='auto' name='nome'>
    <div class="box_bt">
        <i class='demo-icon'>X</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não tem problema responder perguntas antigas, desde que sua resposta seja mais uma alternativa as já existentes :)

Answer (score 0):

Fiz algumas alterações simples no teu Fiddle e funcionou perfeitamente:

```js
$('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');

$('.form_campos_box').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $('.box').toggleClass('focused');
});
```

```css
    body {
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .form-group {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      height: 45px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    
    .control-label {
      opacity: 0.4;
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
      transform-origin: left top;
      transition: 240ms;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .form-group.focused .control-label {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(0.75);
    }
    
    .form_campos {
      height: 20px;
      color: #484848;
      z-index: 1;
      align-self: flex-end;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 5px;
      outline: none;
      border-color: #484848;
      border-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-top-width: 0;
      border-right-width: 0;
      border-left-width: 0;
      background: transparent;
    }
    
    .form_campos:hover,
    .form_campos:focus {
      border-color: #1E90FF;
    }
    
    .form_campos_numeros {
      width: 123px;
    }
   
   
   
    /* BOX INPUT E BOTAO */
    
    .box {
      width: 250px;
      display: flex;
      height: 44px;
      border-color: #484848;
      border-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-top-width: 0;
      border-right-width: 0;
      border-left-width: 0;
    }
    
    .box input {
      outline: 0;
      width: 230px;
      height: 20px;
      border: 0;
      background: transparent;
    }
    
    .box_bt {
      margin-top: 28px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .box_bt:hover {
      color: #1E90FF;
    }
    
    .box:hover, .box.focused {
      border-color: #1E90FF;
    }
    
    .box.focused .control-label {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(0.75);
    }
    
    .form_campos_box {
      color: #484848;
      z-index: 1;
      align-self: flex-end;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 5px;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      outline: none;
    }
    /* FIM BOX INPUT E BOTAO */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='numParcelas'>PARCELAS*</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_numeros' id='numParcelas' name='numParcelas'>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class='box'>
  <label class='control-label' for='auto'>FORNECEDOR*</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos_box' id='auto' name='nome'>
  <div class="box_bt">
    <i class='demo-icon'>X</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links)

Comment: Muito interessante, ainda sou bem novo por aqui e a vontade de ajudar as vezes esbarra nesses detalhes, vou editar minha resposta!

Comment: Sem problema, a intenção é sempre melhorar